# Objective C version of explode()?

Tags: c, objective-c, iphone

If I want to explode a string by parts in PHP into an array, I have the nifty explode() function where I just do the following

```
$mystring = "HI:THERE:HOW";
$stringarray = explode(":", $mystring);
```

And I get

```
$stringarray = (
  [0] = "HI"
  [1] = "THERE"
  [2] = "HOW"
);
```

Is there a similar function in Objective C that explodes a string into an array? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
NSArray *stringArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```