# separating data from array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

mainstr is my string contains:

```
 123;456;23;ns@234;343;3;ner@975;013;742;av@
```

`arr` is my array name.

each location of array contains some string like (should be separated by @)

```
arr[0]=[123;456;23;ns];

arr[1]=[234;343;3;ner];
```

I want to separate each element of `arr[0]` into separate array (they should be separated based on occurrence of `;`
)..

for example

```
newarray[0]=[123] 

newarray[1]=[23]

newarray[2]=[45]

newarray[3]=[ns]
```

how should I do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146462/objective-c-version-of-explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the firstly

```
NSArray *stringArray = [mainstr componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
```

then you can use

```
NSArray *arr0 = [[stringArray objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
and so on...
```