# Hpple, getting text after </span>

Tags: html, ios, parsing, hpple

So I think this is my last Hpple question!  I have found an entry in the HTML doc that I am parsing with Hpple.  I have tried many different queries, but no luck.  Here is a sample of the HTML.[image: HTML]

I can get the text staring with "Today's project" with //div[@class = 'entry-content']/p.  I can also get the next tag with //div[@class = 'entry-content']//a[@title]//* along with all the text after it.  However, as you can see there is still some text after "/span".  However, nothing that I have tried will work.  I have tried looking at the children of the element, tried //div[@class = 'entry-content']/p//text(), //div[@class = 'entry-content']/p//following::*, nothing works.  If anyone has any ideas, I am all ears!!!  Thanks again for all of your time.

EDIT #1
As I try different things I was looking at the HTML.  Under the p tag is the text I need, "Today's project..." then there is a span changing the text color and including a link, followed by more text.  What I need to do is jump over that span to continue reading the text.  Maybe my question should be, how do you jump over a span?  Thanks for looking.

EDIT #2  Well, I am going to start a bounty on this one.  I really need some help.  I have looked everywhere and have tried a ton of different things.  But nothing is working for me.  I can not get the text after that one closed span.  And this format appears often.  The author of the blog I am parsing this for the App sometimes changes the style of her words and I can not get the text after she changes the style.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks again for looking.

EDIT #3  Here is another screen shot of the DOM tree HTML. If you can notice I am parsing the div class "entry content"  The text in question is exposed.  Starts with "Today..." then the span to change the color of the text, I can get that text.  It is the text after that, that I need, " It was one....." right before the close p tag.

[image: Dom Tree]

I also placed the entire HTML on gist. [HERE](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5647076).  The line in question is 102.  Although the HTML did not copy that nicely.  Thanks.

Comment: Isch, opening an anchor tag, opening a span, then closing the anchor tag and then closing the span? Each browser parses this differently, watch out.

Comment: The text is right after closing the span, but before the p tag is closed.

Comment: @DavidKnag, is this what you meant?  I don't know what Isch is, or was that a typo?

Comment: Can you add the html that you are parsing?

Comment: @LuisEspinoza, I am adding another picture of the DOM tree and putting the entire HTML file up on GIST.  Thanks for looking!!!

Comment: We figured it out!  The elements were very deep in the DOM tree.  With the help of @insetoman, we iterated through many generations of children to find all information.  Thanks to all who looked. Can anyone up vote something of mine so I don't have the rep of the devil? (666) ugh!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make some changes in the code to get further on the hierarchy and it worked on your html sample. Note: I'm appending all the entry-content in a single NSMutableString to make it easier.
**Like I warned you in the *comment*, use it with caution. :-)**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
TFHpple *detailParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:data];
NSString *xpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='entry-content']";
NSArray *node = [detailParser searchWithXPathQuery:xpathQueryString];

NSMutableString *test = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

for (TFHppleElement *element in node) {
    for (TFHppleElement *child in element.children) {            
        if (child.content != nil) {
            [test appendString:child.content];
        }
        if ([child.children count]!= 0) {
            for (TFHppleElement *grandchild in child.children) {
                if (grandchild.content != nil) {
                    [test appendString:grandchild.content];
                 }
                for (TFHppleElement *greatgrandchild in grandchild.children) {
                    if (greatgrandchild.content != nil) {
                        [test appendString:greatgrandchild.content];
                    }
                    for (TFHppleElement *greatgreatgrandchild in greatgrandchild.children) {
                        if (greatgreatgrandchild.text != nil) {
                            [test appendString:greatgreatgrandchild.text];
                        }
                        if (greatgreatgrandchild.content != nil) {
                            [test appendString:greatgreatgrandchild.content];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"test = %@", test);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time.  I really appreciate it.  I see what you are doing with the node objectAtIndex:7, but this formatting happens in random places through out.  Also, the span element is sometimes not span.  Like today it was open p tag "Some Text", open em tag "Some more text" close em tag "more text" close p tag.  So in this case I stop parsing after the close em tag and never get the "more text"  I even checked all the children elements that have text as a tag name and the "more text" never shows up.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much.

Comment: I made further study on your html code and the elements that you're having trouble is very bellow on the hierarchy (4 steps, like a greatgreatgrandchild). Using hpple for HTML parser, I don't know if there is an easier way (I hope there is and someone teach us :-) ). I achieve what you want, but beware: use it with caution, extreme caution. I didn't make a lot of tests (tested only with the page you attached) and the code looks horrible... well, I guess don't hurt trying. Going to update my answer. Good luck.

Comment: insetoman, I am making progress and I want to thank you very much.  I am finding that it is very deep in the hierarchy.  But thank you for getting me closer.  And yes, maybe someone can teach us a better way to get it.  I can't believe that the hpple people haven't chimed in on this question!  Or maybe, we just don't get some basic thing about it!!!

Comment: So the bounty is almost up.  But I had a question.  When you said use caution, what did you mean?  And by the way, I have been able to get all the stuff I need!!!  I just have to figure out how to get it into the format that I need.  But thanks for all your help.

Comment: Glad it almost done. I said caution because maybe the site editor could write more information on deeper levels and my code will not get it, maybe it can parse things that you don't want, etc.. My personal opinion is that a parser is extreme fragile because it is too specific. You need to check regularly if it's still working because can easily break if anything in the site changes.

Comment: Well, it works!!  I never knew that you could go that deep! I wish it was easier, but sometimes "looks horrible" works!!  Thanks so much for your help.  ENJOY!

Comment: Thank you Douglas. If I discover something new about http parser that make things easier, I'll let you know. Cheers, mate.

Answer (score 0):

Call me a "raw" guy, but you could read the code as a straight up string and then bust it up into an array by the tags you're going for. This could be done in PHP/Javascript/etc. Then you could just pull the array element containing the text you're looking for. Nothing fancy/external needed.

Example:

```
$string = '<p>text is here</p><p>more text is here</p>';
$string = explode('<p>', $string);

Now $string = [0] => "text is here</p>", [1] => "more text is here</p>"
```

Comment: first off, thanks for looking.  However, I don't know Java or PHP, I only know (if one can ever fully "know" a language!) objective c.  Second, the text I need is after a closed span, your example has text inside an open and closed p tag.  Also, I need to parse more than just text.  There are images, videos, and all sorts of formatting.

Comment: You can bust up a string into an array with Objective C as well even though it's not as powerful or extensive as most other languages.  [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146462/objective-c-version-of-explode) If your array key looks like `first text</span>second text</p>` then you just continue the same process and bust up the array key using the `</span>` as the delimiter. After that just grab the part you need from the new array, remove the `</p>` and VOILA! you have your text.